# Couchbase multi-dimensional keys

Tags: indexing, couchbase

I'm newbie to Couchbase and trying to understand whether it fits my domain.
I have following data:

```
Birth  City    Name
1980   A       John
1981   B       Rick
1982   A       Ase
1983   C       Max
1984   C       Bob
1980   A       Rick
1983   D       John
1982   A       Bob
1985   C       Bob
```

And not getting on how to implement similar to following SQL query:

```
SELECT birth FROM tbl WHERE city in (A,C) and name (Bob, Rick)
```

to get following data:

```
1984   C       Bob
1980   A       Rick
1982   A       Bob
1985   C       Bob
```

One big difference to 'startkey' and 'endkey' view usages is that it's not range selection, it's two different dimension values.

In my real scenario I need to put 1-5000 ID's into 'IN' statement.
The only one way I found is to use indexing and N1ql http://docs.couchbase.com/prebuilt/n1ql/n1ql-dp3/#create-index.html but it seems not the fastest way to access data.

1. What's the best practice to access multi-dimensional key data with lots of keys values?
2. Is it okay to create big 'in' statements in N1ql?

Comment: This looks like a query that SQL would be perfect for... any reason why you need to use Couchbase for this?  Perhaps ElasticSearch integration would help provide more flexible querying for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You should do a view with the emit function, including a key with two dimension values, and returning the value, in this way:

`emit([doc.Name, doc.City], doc.Birth);`

And you will have to query it with the param keys:

`keys=[["Bob", "A"], ["Bob", "C"], ["Rick", "A"], ["Rick", "C"]]`

Comment: It works for small selections, but if I have like 100-200 IDs for first dimension and like 1000 for seconds it would be a mess multiplying it one on another. So thanks, I was thinking about it, but still don't want to go this way.